# How to return records from database using javalite?

Tags: java, activejdbc, javalite

I am using the following line to query the DB:

```
List<PostsCategories> postsCategories = PostsCategories.findBySQL("select category from posts_categories");
```

Instead of returning only `[{category=Miscellaneous},....]` it is returning extra info such as `Model, table, attributes` inside array.

I don't know why it works this way with activejdbc?

```
[Model: com.ngo.org10s.models.PostsCategories, table: 'posts_categories', attributes: {category=Miscellaneous}]
```

How do I simply return the required values?

Comment: I assume you are indeed using Javalite's ActiveJDBC framework and you have in fact tried the simple examples [here](http://javalite.io/activejdbc).

Comment: @DevilsHnd Yeah I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because ActiveJDBC is an ORM == Object Relational Mapping. This means that a model instance contains all attributes to represent a single row in the table.

The method [findBySQL](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/Model.html#findBySQL-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) has JavaDoc that states:

*Ensure that the query returns **all columns** associated with this model, so that the resulting models could hydrate themselves properly*

In other words, if an instance of a `PostsCategories` has just one attribute set, than this is not an ORM anymore.

If you insist on getting just one attribute, use `org.javalite.activejdbc.Base`:

```
List<Map> categories = Base.findAll("select category from posts_categories");
```